# Move two camera with different speed in libgdx

Tags: java, android, camera, box2d, libgdx

I am able to move single camera in libgdx with using box2D. But I have three different layer of background in my game and want to move layer1 with x speed, layer2 with 2x speed and layer3 with 3x speed. Currently I am doing like this:

```
camera.position.x =ActorBody.getPosition().x;
```

but in this scenario as my actor moves forward my camera also moves.How can I use 2 or three camera or is there any more way to do this in more optimize way?

Answer (score 2):

Use parrallaxlayer and parrallaxBackground classes

During making parrallax layer pass velocity of your actor as ratio

```
https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ParallaxBackgound

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/ParallaxTest.java
```